# What's the difference between the given two codes. One gives time limit exceeded when run on ideone and the other works fine

Tags: c++, loops, memory, timeout

1st code: works fine gives success with time of 0sec

```
    int main()
    {
      int n=100000;
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
         {}
      cout<<"ffdfdf";
    }
```

2nd code: gives a time limit exceeded

```
    int main()
    {
      int n=100000;
      bool **a=new bool*[n];
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        bool[i]=new bool[n];
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
         {
           bool[i][j]=1;
         }
      }
      cout<<"ffdfdf";
    }
```

can anyone explain why the two code fragments have a vast time difference.I am not understanding it.

Comment: The two codes are totally different. The second one uses `new` which is quite costly and the first doesn't and you are allocating huge quantities of memory in the second,

Comment: Doing nothing billions of times will usually be significantly faster than doing something like allocating large chunks of memory billions of times.

Comment: In the first program, a good compiler will be able to optimize it all away. In the second program you write to a lot of memory locations.

Comment: And to be honest, doubly-nested `for` loops indicate that the solution you have is `O(n^2)`.  Those types of solutions are the basic causes of "timeout issues".  You probably got `0` seconds due to the compiler removing those two loops, since they do nothing.  Add some code to those loops, and regardless of whether you called `new` or not, don't be surprised if timeout errors will arise.

Comment: Your second code is ill-formed, `bool` is a reserved identifier in c++.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the second program doesn't even compile.

Comment: A `bool` array may have slower access time than an array of `int`, depending on the implementation.  Bit twiddling takes more time than direct access of integers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i did that for the first program..i just put a few arithmetic execution staements inside the for loop but it still passed with almost negligible time

Comment: @HKedia If the compiler sees that those arithmetic statements don't really do anything, then it is free to remove that code.  Also, if you really wanted to write a loop that created a two dimensional dynamically, you shouldn't do it in the way you've done it.  [Here is an example that uses only two calls to `array new`](http://ideone.com/vzRzvc).  The number of calls to the allocator has been reduced to 2 calls instead of 100,000 of them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanx for ur implementation,really liked it

Answer (score 5):

`bool[i]=new bool[n];` is *extremely* expensive cf. the other statements.

A good compiler will optimise out your first program to `cout << "ffdfdf";`, since it will know that the loop doesn't do anything.

Once you've replaced your errant `bool`s with `a`s so the second snippet actually compiles, you'd be advised to pair your `new[]` calls with `delete[]`.

Comment: thanx for the extra info...but even when i try to put in some execution statements inside the loop for the first program,it compiles easily